# Почему возникает ошибка "Validation failed for object='product'"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, валидация

Делаю веб приложение на Java c использованием Spring MVC, Spring Security и Hibernate. Когда хочу добавить продукт меня дает такая ошибка

[image: такая ошибка]

вот это у меня метод который сохраняет информацию

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product,UserDetails userDetails) {
    User user = new User();
    product.setUserUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    productRepository.save(product);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

а этот метод сделает new и сохраняет в базе

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap map, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
    if (userDetails != null) {
        User user = userRepository.findOneByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
        map.addAttribute("currentUser", user);
    }

    map.addAttribute("addCategory", new Category());
    map.addAttribute("allCategories",categoryRepository.findAll());
    map.addAttribute("addProduct",new Product());

    return "home";
}
```

а это в JSP от сюда я даю информацию

```
<spring:form action="saveProduct" modelAttribute="addProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<spring:select path="category">
    <c:forEach items="${allCategories}" var="category">
        <option>
                ${category.name}
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</spring:select>
<spring:input path="name"></spring:input>
<input type="file" name="picture">
<spring:input path="description"></spring:input>
<spring:input path="price"></spring:input>
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</spring:form>
```

а это метод который сохраняет картинку

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/product/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\wasfImage\\" + fileName);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
}
```

что здесь причина за такую ошибку? спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если под путь, по которому происходит добавление продукта, засунуть вывод простой строки (return "ОК";) - что произойдёт?

Comment: И точно POSTовому пути отдаётся запрос POSTом? А то выглядит так, будто GETом пытаемся достучаться до метода, к которому предусмотрено обращение с POSTа.

Comment: Здравствуйте! у меня метод пост потому что я добавлю еще фото там я использую enctype="Multipart form data" а когда надо добавить фото там обязательно должен быть пост а гет это home этот метод вернет обратно в jsp там нет отношения с jsp

Comment: При обращении к какому пути возникает ошибка Whitelabel Error? /saveProduct? Если да - как к нему обращаетесь? Просто в строке поиска браузера пишете путь? Если да - то в этом причина ошибки. Если нет - прошу описать последовательность действий, приводящих к появлению ошибки. Прям по пунктам: 1) запускаю сборку, 2) сборка завершается успешно, 3) запускается контейнер (tomcat, glassfish, что угодно...), 4) открывается браузер, 5) я .... и далее. Пока не дойдём до N)Появляется сообщени об ошибке Whitelabel error.

Comment: 1) запускаю сборку, 2) сборка завершается успешно, 3) запускается контейнер (tomcat), 4) открывается браузер, 5) я заполняю все ячейки 6) когда нажимаю добавить дает эту ошибку а URL такой http://localhost:8080/saveProduct

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить параметр в метод обработки выгружаемого файла

```
 @RequestParam("picture") MultipartFile picture
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но такой у меня есть вот    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\wasfImage\\" + fileName);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
}

Comment: Нет, это не такой

Comment: а куда эту строку положить?

Comment: public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product,UserDetails userDetails)

Comment: корочи вся ошибка связанно с картинкой?

Comment: у вас картинка не принималась, что еще, могут быть другие ошибки, но это потом.

Comment: спасибо огромное